# Create an enum category based on an enum

Tags: java, enums, java-8, java-stream

I have multiple statuses which is stored in an enum.

```
public enum Status {
    IS_A("isA"),
    IS_B("isB"),
    FP_ERR("fp_err"),
    FP_BLAH("fp_blah"),
    CORRECT("correct")

    private final String value;

    Status(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I want to create categories based on these statuses without modifiying the Status enum class, in the following manner.

```
public enum Category {
    CategoryA("CategoryA",Status.IS_A, Status.IS_B),
    CategoryB("CategoryB",Status.FP_ERR, Status.FP_BLAH).
    CategoryC("CategoryC",Status.Correct);

    private List<Status> status;
    private String category;

    private static final Map<Status, String> VALUE_MAP = Stream.of(Category.values()) 

    Category(String category, Status ... status) {
        this.status = Arrays.asList(status);
        this.category = category;
    }

    public static String getCategory(Status status) {
        //Retrun category based on Status type
        String category = VALUE_MAP.get(status);
        return category;
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out how to store the value of each category with their status in the map VALUE_MAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your initialization to a `static` block, you could do this:

```
private static final EnumMap<Status, String> VALUE_MAP = new EnumMap<>(Status.class);
static {
    Arrays.stream(Category.values()).forEach(category -> {
        category.status.forEach(status -> {
            VALUE_MAP.put(status, category.category);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You ought to use `EnumMap` rather than `HashMap`. Otherwise a fine suggestion.

Comment: Try to find solutions without `forEach` first, e.g. `private static final Map<Status, String> VALUE_MAP = Arrays.stream(values()).collect(() -> new EnumMap<>(Status.class), (m,c) -> c.status.forEach(s->m.put(s, c.category)), Map::putAll);`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `VALUE_MAP` at all. When retrieving `category` by `Status` you just need to go through all `Category.values()` and find the one which contains the requested `Status`:

```
public static String getCategory(Status status) {
    for (Category category : values()) {
        if (category.status.contains(status)) {
            return category.category;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is less efficient than using a `Map`.

Comment: No, if there're only 3 values in enum.

Comment: The efficiency difference is hard to tell, if the `Map` is a `HashMap`, but for whatever reason, people seem to constantly ignore the existence of `EnumMap`, designed for mapping `enum` keys to a value and therefore definitely more efficient than a nested loop (mind that `contains` on a `List` is a linear search as well)…